# VanillaModal How to keep close jpeg always on the upper right of modal box?

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

I'm using vanillamodal (http://cocopon.me/app/vanillabox/demo.html) and want to position the close button always on the upper right of any modal box.
My code: http://jsfiddle.net/bcj5S/

```
.vnbx-content > iframe {
border-width: 0;
vertical-align: middle;
margin: 0 auto;
```

}

```
.vnbx-close {
background-image: url("img/close.jpg");
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 12px;  
width:670px; height:29px; display:block; z-index:3200; position:absolute; top:7px;
right:75px; cursor:pointer; outline: 0;}
}
```

[image: Good!]

[image: Bad!]

Comment: Your fiddle isn't showing me the close button.

Comment: Yes, but the point of JSFiddle is being able to see it in action and tweak it.  Otherwise you could just post the source.  Is there a way you could make a fiddle showing just a dialog with the close button as it would normally render?

Comment: I'm not sure how to upload a jpeg to jsfiddle. Here's all the code and relevant files in a zip though http://www.4shared.com/zip/yAYoUVGYba/Darrien_Website.html

Comment: You can see the issue here (http://imdarrien.com/). Compare 'about me' and 'maru' :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the close button has to be positioned using the coordinate system of the modal dialog box that you are displaying.  If dialog is positioned relatively, absolutely, or "fixedly," then, within that block, using absolute positioning, you place a close button in the upper right corner or anywhere you want.

Here's a quick fiddle to illustrate CSS-only dialog modal: [CSS-only Modal](http://jsfiddle.net/74g2F/).

Notice that the modal itself is positioned absolutely and the x-element is placed absolutely also using the coordinate system of the modal:

```
<input type = "checkbox" id = "closeToggle" />
<label for = "closeToggle">Open</label>
<div id = "modal">
    <label for = "closeToggle"></label>
        Content goes here...
</div>
```

And here's CSS:

```
input[type = "checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

label {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#modal {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

#modal > label {
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: -10px;
}

#modal > label:before {
    content: "x";
}

input:checked ~ #modal {
    display: block;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -100px 0 0 -100px;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It all seems to be dependent on what you're setting the box relative to.  It should be set relative to the top left corner when it's set to the top right.

Without a good code sample (which by looking around seems to be hard to get) I couldn't give you any specifics.

EDIT: If you already have scripts in place, you could set the `margin-right` of the box to the width of the pop-up using a script of some sort.

Comment: I can get it to behave properly when on the right side of the modal but can't get it too lock to the left side corner. Oh well. I guess having the close button on the right side is more user friendly anyways.

Comment: If you wanted, you could move your links to the right as well so that the mouse is in the right area.  Oh, and nice Totoro BTW!